# Do I need x264 in FFmpeg to extract subtitles

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles

I'm planning to compile my own FFmpeg build and I want to disable unnecessary libraries (e.g., with GPL license)

I need to use FFmpeg only for extracting subtitles https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ExtractSubtitles

Does this function requires x264? `ffmpeg -i videofile.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.srt`

Do I need to build FFmpeg with `--enable-libx264` or can I build `--disable-libx264` and it's still going to work (subtitles extracting)?

Comment: Subtitles are not video codecs, you don't need any video codecs for extracting subtitles.

Comment: x264 doesn't decode any subtitles, so you don't need it.

Comment: @Gyan thanks, I'm going to create a list of what do I need only for extracting subtitles (to make ffmpeg binary size as less as possible), can you suggest something else for disabling (`--disable-...`)?

Comment: If you don't intend to convert any subs; all you need are the native demuxers and the data muxer. If you want to convert to ASS or SRT, then you'll want the ass/srt encoders and muxers, as well as the decoder for the sub format.

Comment: @Gyan yes when I extract subs I'm trying to extract any subs as SRT, so I'm not removing next libs: libass, freetype, fontconfig

Comment: Not required - those are for drawing characters - your task requires extracting or converting one text file to another. libass is for subtitles filter which paints on video frames; fontconfig/freetype is for converting text to glyphs for use by drawtext filter.

Comment: @Gyan so e.g. libass isn't required for converting ass to srt?

Comment: No, it's only required for the ass and subtitles filters.

Comment: @Gyan thank you, I hope it will decrease size of binary file

Comment: @Gyan I also have `--extra-libs="-lexpat -lm" ` in sh build file, I'm not sure if need those (libexpat, libm)

Comment: libm may be required elsewhere but libexpat - probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x264 is only required for video. If you just want to extract tracks from a MKV container then all you need is mkvextract.

Comment: it's not necessarily mkv container, could be any one which includes subtitles, does FFmpeg use mkvextract?

Comment: Probably not, since it would normally handle the tracks itself.

Comment: x264 is an encoder - it doesn't decompress video either; it only compresses to H264.

Comment: @Gyan: That sounds like something you should tell the asker.

Comment: I guess I still will use FFmpeg (cause it's cross-platform, even for Android), also FFmpeg uses some other dependencies (like libass, freetype, fontconfig) and mb they expand the possibilities for extracting different type of subtitles

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I'm addressing the first sentence of your answer.